# Svelte Store update

Tags: svelte, svelte-store

I'm having a hard time understanding how to update my store in the same file in which it's defined. I have the following store definition:

```
export const myStore = writable({
    myList: [],
    myOtherList: []
});
```

In a later function, say I want to update `myList` to another list `sourceList`. I've looked at a bunch of the update function examples, and none make any sense to me. What I want to do is something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
myStore.myList = sourceList
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out the appropriate `myStore.update()` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Svelte file it's just:

```js
$myStore.myList = sourceList
```

Without `$` syntax you could do:

```js
myStore.update(current => ({ ...current, myList: sourceList }))
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I don't understand the syntax inside the brackets though...

Comment: It creates a new object and [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `current` properties, essentially creating a shallow copy. Adding `myList` overwrites the existing key and thus old value.